# ECS using bridge network mode unable to access the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a Java app running within a Docker container on ECS. Recently a new requirement arose for it to access the outside internet. This was not an issue in our development environments, but once in prod suddenly the Docker instance was unable to access the internet.

After digging around a bit I changed the network mode from 'bridge' to 'host' which fixed the problem.  Thing is, I don't want to use bridge mode.

What I can't figure is why it would be different between environments.. they task definitions etc are exactly the same.

I have checked the security groups.  In fact, I have checked the the host EC2 can access the internet.. it can. And anyway all that is eliminated by the fact it works in 'host' mode. Also, the EC2 instance is spawn from the same AMI as the other environments.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you have a NAT-Gateway (VPC -> NAT-Gateway) assigned to the same subnet as the EC2 Instance (the private subnet) and a Internet-Gateway assigned to the public subnet?

The route table of your private subnet should look like this:

```
| Destination   | Target      |
| 10.20.0.0/16  | local       |
| 0.0.0.0/0     | nat-00d.... |
```

The route table of your public subnet should look like this:

```
| Destination   | Target      |
| 10.20.0.0/16  | local       |
| 0.0.0.0/0     | igw-046.... |
```

.. assuming 10.20.8.0/21 is your public subnet and 10.20.16.0/21 is your private subnet.

Then you should have internet connectivity on your ECS Service in bride network mode.

Comment: Hi alwe and thanks for your reply.

So yes, I have the mentioned containers running in EC2 located in private subnets lets call them Subnet1 and Subnet2.  Both Subnet1 and Subnet2 have the 0.0.0.0/0 route through to a NAT gateway.  All public subnets have the 0.0.0.0/0 route through to an IGW.  NATS are all active.

Comment: My private subnets are 10.0.0.0/19 and 10.0.32.0/19, public 10.0.128.0/20, 10.0.144.0/20 and 10.0.160.0/20. The route tables read as follows:

Private 1:
10.0.0.0/16 -> local
0.0.0.0/0 -> NAT

Private 2:
10.0.0.0/16 -> local
0.0.0.0/0 -> NAT

Public:
10.0.0.0/16 -> local
0.0.0.0/0 -> IGW

Same setup works in our dev environment.

Comment: The only difference I can see between dev and prod setup is that we have removed the default VPC in prod. Would this have any affect?